# Is it feasible to use a treadmill and maintain the sanity of your downstairs neighbors?

Tags: running, exercise-equipment, treadmill

I live on the second floor and while I like running it'd be nice to not have to go out in the cold sometimes. I'm afraid using a treadmill wouldn't sit well with the downstairs neighbors. Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: This does depend on the build quality of the treadmill, how well isolated the building is and your own manner of running. So another person's experience might not help you, rather you should focus on how to make it feasible given your circumstances

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a link to some good advice: [How to Use a Treadmill on the Second Floor](http://www.livestrong.com/article/323630-how-to-use-a-treadmill-on-the-second-floor/).

I would think 90% of the noise/vibration issue will be based on the construction of the house/apt.  Without thick, well insulated floors, you'll need to add foam mats until you reach the level of 'quiet' acceptable to everyone and hopefully not to many mats to take away from the use of the treadmill.  Lift weights, unless you drop them, there's little noise and you'll get a better workout.

Comment: Nice find! But while the lifting weights can certainly be quieter, its no help if you're planning to resume running marathons after the winters over eh? ;-)

Comment: @Ivo - Actually weight lifting does help with running - it builds stronger muscles making the body more effective during aerobic exercise.

Comment: Yes, but if you don't actually run, it'll hurt your endurance, because you're not actually running anymore. No amount of lifting weights will allow you to run a marathon, but it is a good exercise nonetheless.